# Can we avoid using django session to work with request body params data?

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I have two django restframework classes(POST and GET)respectively, as seen below

```
class demo(CreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = DummySerializer

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        ID = request.data.get("ID")
        org = request.data.get("org")
        ent= request.data.get("ent")


        request.session['ID '] = ID 
        request.session['org'] = org
        request.session['ent'] = ent
        request.session.save()  



class demo1(ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = MySerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        ID = request.session.get("ID")
        org = request.session.get("org")
        ent= request.session.get("ent")
```

I have two queries:

1. My aim is to `fetch` those 3 params from `request body` in `demo`
   class and add it to a session and then use the values in `demo1`
   class for further data manipulation. So, I migrated the default
   django in-built apps in the development sqlite DB and I could see
   the flow of the data from `demo` class to `demo1` class. But in my
   actual working environment, I am trying to avoid the session
   migrations until I don't have any further options.
2. In a new django app which I have created in my working environment, in the models.py I have define the structure of an existing table from my MySQL db. Hence, if I do a migrations and then mnigrate, will the migrations going to make any further changes in the MYSQL tables, or it will only compare the existing schema and then just create a migration files?

So, please let me know if there is any other work around to achieve the goal.

thank you

Comment: Django migrations are designed to handle changes to the database schema. it will see earlier migrations and compare to it and then create new migration file for you.